# AStyle: indentation for one-line block

Tags: c++, astyle

Is it possible using [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) formatting tool add indention for brackets and parens in one-line block?

What I have:

```
int f(int i)const{return 42;}
```

What I want to reach:

```
int f(int i) const { return 42; }
```

Default formatting with `--keep-one-line-blocks` option adds only one space after `const`:

```
int f(int i)const {return 42;}
```

Comment: I know clangformat does take care of this.